# How to fix Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string [PHP] [HTML]

Tags: php, html

so hopefully i ask my question in the proper manner. I am trying to code a calculator that will display an error when someone tries to fill in a letterinstead of a number. How do i get this to work without a "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string" stopping the code. And then the Exception should be shown next to the input field.

I add a screenshot of the result i am trying to get and i will give the code i have sofar.[

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<?php

$number1 = "";
$number2 = "";
$result = "";
$calculate = "";

if (isset($_GET['calculate'])) {
    $number1 = $_GET['number1'];
    $number2 = $_GET['number2'];
    $calculate = $_GET['calculate'];

    function isValidNumber1($number1)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($number1)) {
            throw new Exception("Number 1 is not a number!");
        }
    }
    try {
        isValidNumber1($number1);
        $result = $number1 + $number2;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }


    switch ($calculate) {
        case "Add":
            $result = $number1 + $number2;
            break;
        case "Substract":
            $result = $number1 - $number2;
            break;
        case "Multiply":
            $result = $number1 * $number2;
            break;
        case "Divide":
            $result = $number1 / $number2;
            break;
        case "Modulo":
            $result = $number1 % $number2;
            break;
    }
}

?>

<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <form action="" method="get" id="calculator">

        <label for="number1">Number 1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="number1" value="<?php echo $number1; ?>"><br><br>
        <label for=" number2">Number 2:</label>
        <input type="text" name="number2" value="<?php echo $number2; ?>"><br><br>

        <?php
        echo "<p>Operation:  $calculate</p>";
        echo "<p>Result: $result</p>";
        ?>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Add">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Substract">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Multiply">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Divide">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Modulo">
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKw6A.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix the current implementation

- you need to add the `switch` statements inside the `try` block,
- so when the validation exception fire it will escape running it
- and about showing the error beside the input you can set the `exception message` in a `variable` and print it beside the input " ,

your implementation after those edits will looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<?php

$number1 = "";
$number2 = "";
$result = "";
$calculate = "";
$number1Error = '';

if (isset($_GET['calculate'])) {
    $number1 = $_GET['number1'];
    $number2 = $_GET['number2'];
    $calculate = $_GET['calculate'];
    $errors = [];
    
    function isValidNumber1($number1)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($number1)) {
            throw new Exception("Number 1 is not a number!");
        }
    }
    
    
    try {
        isValidNumber1($number1);
        $result = $number1 + $number2;
        
        switch ($calculate) {
        case "Add":
        var_dump($number1);
            $result = $number1 + $number2;
            break;
        case "Substract":
            $result = $number1 - $number2;
            break;
        case "Multiply":
            $result = $number1 * $number2;
            break;
        case "Divide":
            $result = $number1 / $number2;
            break;
        case "Modulo":
            $result = $number1 % $number2;
            break;
    }
    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $number1Error = $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        
    }


    
}

?>

<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <form action="" method="get" id="calculator">

        <label for="number1">Number 1: </label>
        <input type="text" name="number1" value="<?php echo $number1; ?>"> <?php echo $number1Error; ?><br><br>
        <label for=" number2">Number 2:</label>
        <input type="text" name="number2" value="<?php echo $number2; ?>"><br><br>

        <?php
        echo "<p>Operation:  $calculate</p>";
        echo "<p>Result: $result</p>";
        ?>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Add">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Substract">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Multiply">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Divide">
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Modulo">
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Omar, it almost works. When i first run the code i now get "Warning: Undefined variable $number1Error'"  refering to the variable after the input field. How to solve this?

Comment: just initialize it  `$number1Error = '';` before `try`   lilke the mentioned example in the answer

Comment: I did use the code you advised but i still get the warning.

Comment: it's my bad, you need to define it even before `isset` condition, example updated kindly check

Comment: Thank you Omar for your swift reply. I moved the initialization of $number1Error = ''; up above the first if statement and now it works.